# Accessing Spring-WS service with JAX-RPC client model

Tags: spring-ws, jax-rpc

I have deployed a service using spring-ws and accessed it using

```
<bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory"/>

<bean id="webServiceTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
<constructor-arg ref="messageFactory"/>
<property name="defaultUri" value="http://localhost:6060/SpringMVC/ws"/>
</bean>

<bean id="webServiceClient" class="client.EchoTestClient">
<property name="defaultUri" value="http://localhost:6060/SpringMVC/ws/"/>
</bean>
```

Can we use any of the JAX-RPC client handing method( Static Stub, Dynamic Proxy or Dynamic Invocation Interface) to access these web services? If yes then how?
What I understand is that Spring-WS implementation is quite different from JAX-RPC and JAX-WS implementation and we cannot access these using JAX-RPC. Please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

JAX-RPC is the pre-cursor to modern web-services, and is now obsolete. Both Spring-WS and JAX-WS work with modern (WS-I) web services, and will interoperate with each other (as well as with other WS-I-compliant stacks like WCF), but JAX-RPC is out there on its own, and isn't compatible with much of anything exception itself.